# Enumerating all mazes of given size n*m

Tags: python, combinatorics

I would like to enumerate all the possible mazes of size n*m (For instance, this is a 3*4 maze[image]). I'm doing that in a Python program and have trouble doing so.
I thought I could breaking up the surface in smaller areas, choosing one from a list of mazes of the smaller size and concatenating, but I find it bulky.
Is there a more elegant and inexpensive method ?

Comment: it would help if we knew what exactly you mean by a maze, do you mean something like this (https://krazydad.com/mazes/)? Do the mazes need to be valid with a solution?

Comment: Just added an illustration. I'm talking about the rectangular regular kind. All I need is the maze to be connected.

Comment: It is easy to generate every possible maze (with or without a solution). One naïve way would be to then filter out the ones that have a solution

Comment: You could do a DFS to find if it has a solution.

Comment: @ajay I thought of that, I'm just not sure what the execution time will be for "big" mazes … Thanks though !

Comment: So the total number of mazes will be 2 ^ (number of edges). Number of edges will be (m+1) * (n+1). So yes, the execution will be exponential in m*n.

Comment: But so will be your number of solutions. Since you have to enumerate them (not just count) your problem's minimum execution time is exponential.

Comment: @ajay of coures it will anyway be, I was rather wondering if there was a way to make it quicker by not generating all the "pseudo"-mazes (and then filtering) but generating the ones with a solution directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that:

- maze has starting and ending cell,
- there should be unique path between starting and ending cell,
- every cell has to be visited.

First step is to find possible pairs of start and end cells. Here is good to thread pairs same regarding
symmetries (rotations and mirrors.)

Simpler version is that path between start and end passes through all cells. In that case problem is same as finding all hamiltonian paths in a (grid) graph. Check this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36368/efficient-way-to-count-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-grid-graph-for-a-given-pair-of-vert).

More realistic version is that maze can have dead-ends. In that case graph of maze is a tree with starting cell as a root, and ending cell is a leave. That is more general case than upper version. In this case problem is to find trees with these properties. As first version I would go with simple implementation.
Make DFS from start cell and first find path to end cell, after that traverse not visited cells starting from some path cell different than end cell.